# Why is $N =$ infinity for an isochoric process?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

For a general polytropic process, $PV^N$ = constant. In case of an isochoric process, the value of this $N$ is taken equal to infinity. But we know that $V$ is constant for an isochoric process.

I don't understand how taking $N =$ infinity gives $V$ constant.

Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll rewrite the polytropic relation $PV^n = C$ where $C$ is some constant as $$\frac P{P_0} \left(\frac V{V_0}\right)^n = 1\tag{1}$$ where $P_0$ and $V_0$ are known values of the pressure and volume at some point in time.

There are two special cases where the expression says nothing about the relationship between pressure and volume. One is $n=0$. In the limit $n\to0$, the term $(V/V_0)^n \to 1$, leaving $P/P_0 = 1$ or $P=P_0$. In other words, $n=0$ denotes an isobaric process, with the volume unspecified by the relationship.

Rewriting the polytropic relationship once again as $$\left(\frac P{P_0}\right)^{1/n}\frac V{V_0} = 1\tag{2}$$
This leads to the other special case. In the limit $n\to\infty$, the term $(P/P_0)^{1/n} \to 1$, leaving $V/V_0 = 1$ or $V=V_0$. In other words, $n=\infty$ denotes an isochoric process; here the pressure is unspecified.